# .html() on object element with Quicktime classid strips param tags in Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, object, parameters

When using .html() to retrieve html containing an object which contains param tags, the latter will be stripped in IE8, returning an empty object element. Here is a jsfiddle that proves this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/L9rra/1/.

Update: I would like to know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Not really a question. Are you looking for a workaround?

Comment: You seem to have a similar problem to the fella here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081656/object-param-jquery. Scroll down to the second answer.

Comment: @Tomm: I tried your idea here: http://jsfiddle.net/L9rra/4/ but no luck in IE8

Comment: @Tomm: Your idea did get me to thinking about other plugins. I would like to give you credit for answering this question as I have it figured out here: http://jsfiddle.net/L9rra/6/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you see some kind of race condition. In IE I see the object code with all params all the time, but in Firefox I get a div tag with a lot of inline styles instead of the object half the time.

You are binding the `ready` event from the `load` event, so the code will not actually run when the `ready` event occurs, but when the `load` event occurs. Just use the `ready` event that jsfiddle provides. This always shows the object code with all the params when I test it:

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/L9rra/3/

Comment: Yes, but does it show in IE8? This is the important issue. When I test your link, it does not.