# jquery append element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I use `$('#flashObj').append();` to add text to the two areas that say "append_HERE" in the below code?

edit: what if I had it stored in a variable as a string and wanted to change the values that way?

```
var flashLayout = '<div id="flashObj">'+
    '<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="200" height="20">'+
        '<param name="movie" value="dbs/js/singlemp3player.swf?file=append_HERE.mp3&autoStart=false&backColor=000000&frontColor=ffffff&songVolume=90" />'+
        '<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />'+
        '<embed wmode="transparent" width="200" height="20" src="dbs/js/singlemp3player.swf?file=append_HERE.mp3&autoStart=false&backColor=000000&frontColor=ffffff&songVolume=90" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />'+
    '</object></div>'
```

Comment: Ugh??? Ahhhhh! [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/append)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript (and jQuery) work with DOM nodes (elements as objects) not 'text'.

You can either get that code as HTML text and do a regular string replace like so:

```
var f = $('#flashObj');
f.html( f.html().replace('append_HERE', 'append_HERE_the_new_stuff') );
```

---

Or, even better you should avoid playing with HTML as text and instead change the attribute itself:

```
var f = $('#flashObj param:first');
f.attr('value', f.attr('value').replace('append_HERE', 'append_HERE_the_new_stuff') );

var f = $('#flashObj embed');
f.attr('src', f.attr('src').replace('append_HERE', 'append_HERE_the_new_stuff') );
```

---

**PS**: You will probably want to do a global replace using a regular expression since `"bar bar".replace("bar", "foo")` returns `'foo bar'`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use `append()` method for for manipulating the attribute values. Try using `attr` method to get and set the attribute value.

Try this.

```
var $embed = $('#flashObj embed');
var $paramMovie = $('#flashObj param[name=movie]');
$embed.attr('src', $embed.attr('src')
                   .replace('append_HERE', 'yourTextGoesHere'));
$paramMovie.attr('value', $paramMovie.attr('value')
                         .replace('append_HERE', 'yourTextGoesHere'));
```

Comment: Huh? why are you doing paramMove minus a movie element (which, by the way, doesn't exist)? Also, why are you replacing the stuff in `name` attribute when it's the value that needs to be changed?

Comment: @ChristianSciberras - That was missed while typing but thanks. Corrected it now, care to remove the down vote?

Answer (score 0):

you would not do that...

append is not ment for that purpose... have a look at this post:

[object, param, jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081656/object-param-jquery)

it might help

Answer (score 0):

The append() method here really won't help you, as it will just append an element to the object element. You probably want to use something like the [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone will correct me if I'm wrong but I would say you're trying to use the append function incorrectly.  I use would use to *append* text or markup to the end of something, not insert it into the middle.

I'm not sure on your code but I think a better solution would be to build up your  element in your javascript code using the jQuery attr() function `$('param').attr('value','the value you need')` etc...

Hope this helps!

James

Answer (score 0):

append() will not help you to replace the text, plus the whole concept is not going to work anyway. You should remove object and embed from DOM, recreate them with your new values and inject them back again (append() can help in that case)

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't use .append() for that.
You can do it this way (not the most elegant code, but should work just fine):

```
var param = $("#flashObj").children("object").children("param").filter("[name='movie']")
var embed = $("#flashObj").children("object").children("embed")

//Change the value on the <param>
param.val(param.val().replace("append_HERE", "New Value Goes Here"));

//Change the value on the <embed>
embed.attr("src", embed.attr("src").replace("append_HERE", "New Value Goes Here"));
```

Just replace "New Value Goes Here" with what you're trying to insert.