# Using jQuery to set values inside attributes of an Object element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

Here is the rundown of the problem:

```
console.log($("#clippy")); //For testing purposes. The element is properly selected.

//Next, I need to grab the text value I want to be copied into the clipboard...
var textToCopy = $(".permalink input[name='link']").text();

//How can I paste the value inside textToCopy inside the appropriate areas:
//Here's the exact HTML I need to manipulate, with the two params I need to modify.
//Labeled: "<-----HERE!"

/*<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
        width="110"
        height="25"
        id="clippy" >
    <param name="movie" value="/flash/clippy.swf"/>
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
    <param NAME="FlashVars" value="text=sergio is the best champ"> <-------HERE!
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#fff">
    <embed src="../../Public/javascripts/clippy.swf"
            width="110"
            height="25"
            name="clippy"
            quality="high"
            allowScriptAccess="always"
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
            pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
            FlashVars="text=sergio is the best champ" <--------AND HERE!
            bgcolor="#fff"
    />
</object>*/
```

Assuming the value of `textToCopy` was "Welcome to The Matrix.", this would be the resulting HTML:

```
 /*<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
        width="110"
        height="25"
        id="clippy" >
    <param name="movie" value="/flash/clippy.swf"/>
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
    <param NAME="FlashVars" value="text=Welcome to The Matrix."> <-------HERE!
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#fff">
    <embed src="../../Public/javascripts/clippy.swf"
            width="110"
            height="25"
            name="clippy"
            quality="high"
            allowScriptAccess="always"
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
            pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
            FlashVars="text=Welcome to The Matrix." <--------AND HERE!
            bgcolor="#fff"
    />
</object>*/
```

Comment: `$('#clippy').find('param[name="FlashVars"]').val(textToCopy);` and `$('#clippy').find('embed').attr('FlashVars', textToCopy);`

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081656/object-param-jquery. See answer 3.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 6):

You can access the parameters of an object by finding the param by name:

```
$('#clippy').find('param[name="FlashVars"]').val(textToCopy);
```

You can access the attributes of the embed within the object like this:

```
$('#clippy').find('embed').attr('FlashVars', textToCopy);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is now properly setting the data in the HTML as I need it. However the lib is copying the text set when the page is first rendered, not the text that is set via this jQuery code. Do I need to somehow reload clippy library in order for it to copy the text I added in dynamically after the page loaded?

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle with your problem? You can include the library for clippy there. Then I could give you a better explanation as to why you're experiencing what you're experiencing. I've never used clippy.

Comment: Sure I'll do that and post a comment here with the link. Thanks for your time.