# Converting Javascript string to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, string, hyperlink

I am trying to create a website that will play multiple avi files with just the one avi player plugin on the right, and a list of buttons on the left which each will run a java function to change the source avi file on the HTML plugin below. So my seudo code function below:

```
<script>

function myFunction()
{
var filepath = "C:\hello.avi";
htmlobject = filepath;
}
```

So that I can press a button to run that script which will change the variable below

```
    <OBJECT 
   ID="MediaPlayer" 
   <PARAM NAME="FileName" VALUE=                              FILEPATH>
   <PARAM NAME="TransparentAtStart" Value="false">
   <PARAM NAME="AutoStart" Value="true">
   <PARAM NAME="AnimationatStart" Value="true">
   pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/isapi/redir.dll?       prd=windows&sbp=mediaplayer&ar=Media&sba=Plugin&"
   src=                                                       FILEPATH
   Name=MediaPlayer
   displaySize=0></embed>
   </OBJECT>
```

So in theory after i have pressed the button changing the file path i can press play on the avi player and it will play the avi file.

So im hoping someone will know the answer to this or tell me a better way of going about this whole idea. Thank you for looking.

Comment: did it work in practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your HTML has some problems.

This block of code:

```
    pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/isapi/redir.dll?       prd=windows&sbp=mediaplayer&ar=Media&sba=Plugin&"
   src=                                                       FILEPATH
   Name=MediaPlayer
   displaySize=0>
```

...is missing the opening of an `<EMBED` tag and maybe a `type=...` attribute or some other content.

Secondly, while HTML normally allows JavaScript to dynamically change values, in the case of object/param, you apparently cannot. The approach recommended by some posters at [object, param, jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081656/object-param-jquery) is to rebuild the object element completely.

For your reference, you will need to know how to target HTML elements in order for your JavaScript to interact with it. Although there are built-in ways to do this which you should learn if you wish to improve in JavaScript (e.g., `document.getElementById()`), you may also find a framework such as the popular [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to make this (and other dynamic behaviors) easier and work in a cross-browser fashion.

Basically, I recommend you first take the time to read a book on the basics of dynamic HTML. It doesn't need to be a complex book. Just something to get going. Or go through a comprehensive tutorial. A popular site is http://w3schools.com  . Although people have rightly criticized it for having some false information, some of which [they have corrected](http://readwrite.com/2011/01/17/w3schools-responds-to-w3fools#awesm=~o8AOx9WLoznMR9) (and misleading people by its name in seeming to associate it with an official standards body), overall, I think it is one of the more attractive and well explained tutorial sites for beginners.

Comment: Yeah I knew that the plugin wouldn't work because i cut most of it out since i just needed an example admittedly I am new to HTML hated the idea a few years ago but at what it can do with various other tools like JavaScript it has peaked my interest. Thanks for your help and guidance.