# Replacing part of an object's param value with value from an anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If you've got the following:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="609" width="1000" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=jonnyflyspeed" bgcolor="#000000">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />
<param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" />
<param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=CHANNELNAMEHERE&auto_play=true&start_volume=75" />
</object>
```

Is there any way to change `value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=CHANNELNAMEHERE&auto_play=true&start_volume=75"`, specifically the CHANNELNAMEHERE part of the value by using a normal text link? For example:

```
<a href="#" value="NEWCHANNELNAME">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "using a normal text link"? You want the user to be able to change that parameter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [object, param, jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081656/object-param-jquery)

Comment: Note that an `value` isn't (unless I'm seriously mistaken) a valid attribute for an `a` element. (Comment edited to correct the problem of typing-stupidity. Sorry.)

Comment: Wha? An `href` attribute is *required* for an anchor.

Comment: have you tried re-creating the DOM object element with all the information when the "normal text link" changes?

Comment: Sorry, sorry: massive attack of stupid...since edited. :$

Comment: Basically I will be loading a list of Twitch channel names and want to  have the player on the screen, then when you click one of the other channel names, the player reloads the chosen channel. Thinking about it, I probably need the whole object to reload as I want it to reload the player to load the new stream... So essentially I need a standard code (the object code posted above) that updates with the new channel name when you click the link...

Comment: @Leo, see my last reply which is essentially that I think, just not sure how to go about it. If possible I don't want to reload the whole page which I'm sure is possible?

Comment: Sorry, i was late to answer you BN, i was going to post this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sdJ7S/4/, but you got a simmylar solution yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it by way of reloading the whole object with new details:

The link is:

```
<a onclick="changeChannel('CHANNELNAME')">

<script>
function changeChannel(intValue){
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="609" width="1000" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel='+intValue+'" bgcolor="#000000"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel='+intValue+'&auto_play=true&start_volume=75" /></object>'

}
</script>
```